# Converting pandas Timestamp to POSIX epoch time using strftime()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Timestamp, and I want to convert it to a string representation as a POSIX epoch timestamp. I can make the timestamp, and check it a couple of ways:

```py
>>> import pandas as ps
>>> ts = ps.Timestamp("2020-06-16 07:00:00-04:00")
>>> ts
Timestamp('2020-06-16 07:00:00-0400', tz='pytz.FixedOffset(-240)')
>>> ts.timestamp()
1592305200.0
>>> ts.value
1592305200000000000
```

And that value checks out:

```sh
$ TZ=EST5EDT date -d @1592305200 -Iseconds
2020-06-16T07:00:00-04:00
```

But if I try to get that value formatted as a string, I get something deeply odd:

```py
>>> ts.strftime("%s")
'1592319600'
```

That value, which should be independent of any time zones, is incorrect.

```sh
$ TZ=EST5EDT date -d @1592319600 -Iseconds
2020-06-16T11:00:00-04:00
```

Is this expected behavior from a pandas Timestamp? If not, what am I likely doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*To answer your question, the behavior of Pandas Timestamp is expected. However, using small case `%s` can yield very unexpected results and, thus, can not be recommended. I'll provide some insight below.*

## Background for the solution

When using `datetime`, Python actually calls the platform C library’s `strftime()` function. Thus, format codes might vary across platforms. It is important to note that the small case `%s` is not supported by the Python `strftime()`, as seen in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). It works only because it might be supported by your platform function. In some platforms, `%s` [returns](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/strftime.3.en.html) the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 (UTC), but uses your **local** time zone and not the zone, which was specified in the `Timestamp`. Using `%s` would yield totally different values in my time zone. To summarize, **do not use** `.strftime("%s)`, as it might cause some very unexpected results.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp("2020-06-16 07:00:00-0400")
>>> ts.strftime("%s %z")
Out: '1592290800 -0400'
>>> ts = pd.Timestamp("2020-06-16 07:00:00")
>>> ts.strftime("%s %z")
Out: '1592290800 '
```

## The solution

If you want the `Timestamp` as a string, you could use

```
>>> "%d" % ts.timestamp()
Out: '1592305200'
```

*Learning by stackoverflowing,*